# Как избежать повторной отправки данных на сервер при переключении роутинга?

Tags: angular2, angular, angular8

Как избежать повторной отправки данных на сервер при быстром переключении роутинга?

Когда пользоватеть активирует определенный роутинг путь - клиент отправляет запрос на сервер. Пока приходит ответ, пользователь успевает перейти по другом роутингу и вернуть обратно, запросив опять такие же данные.

Как этого избежать?

Comment: кешировать? =).

Comment: почитайте про subscribe. Вам нужно отписаться от подписок при переходе в другой роутинг так как компоненты уничтожаются